# Express $2\cos^2x - 3\sin^2x$ in terms of $\cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to express $2\cos^2x - 3\sin^2x$ in terms of $\cos(2x)$.

I have substituted the $\sin^2x$ using trig identities and have reached:
$5\cos^2x - 3$.

But now I'm really stuck.

Comment: Do you know the formula $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2 x-1$?

Comment: Do you know the [double-angle formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html)?

Answer (score 3):

So $2\cos^{2}x-3\sin^{2}x=5\cos^{2}x -3$ but also $\cos 2x=2\cos^{2}x-1$ substitution give \begin{align*} 2\cos^{2}x-3\sin^{2}x&=5\cos^{2}x -3,\\&=5\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos2x\right)-3,\\&=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{2}\cos 2x.\end{align*}